# Why does the component never returns true?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know why my PrivateRoutes.js won't return  when auth is set to true after the axios call. It will always return

Thank you for your help

PrivateRoutes.js

```
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const PrivateRoutes = () => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    axios.get('http://localhost:3333/user/auth', {
      headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + token }
    })
    .then((response) => {
        setAuth(true);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        setAuth(false);
    })
    
    return ( auth ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to="/"/> )
    
}
```

Comment: Your `PrivateRoutes` component doesn't return anything. You only return from a nested function

Comment: @Konrad And how do I return something after the axis call? I can't manage to get it working

Comment: Your component will unmount now before the axios gets the response back

Comment: and how do I unmount the component after the response is received? @Konrad

Answer (score 1):

There is a third state when the data is not loaded yet

I suggest showing some loading animation while it's loading:

```
import { Outlet, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(undefined);
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

  axios
    .get("http://localhost:3333/user/auth", {
      headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + token },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      setAuth(true);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      setAuth(false);
    });

  if (auth === undefined) return <>loading</>;

  return auth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" />;
};
```